# multiple conditions of `and` and `or` in one awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use multiple 'AND' and 'OR' condition in awk but it is not giving me the desired output. Instead it doesn't read the last `&&` conditions that i have given with time '030000'.

```
awk -F, '{if(substr($2,1,3)=="301" && $15=="996" || $15=="429" && $5>=030000 && $5<=035000) print $2"|"$15"|"$5}' 2017020* | head -10

3014241320|996|235939
3017943809|996|235953
```

Comment: What is your input file? and expected output?

Comment: `||` has lower priority than `&&` (like `+` vs. `*`), so try `... && ($15=="996" || $15=="429") && ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you missed parentheses around the `OR` operation. It should be:

```
if(substr($2,1,3)=="301" && ($15=="996" || $15=="429") && $5>=030000 && $5<=035000) ...
```

See [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 2):

In awk, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so your condition actually means

```
    (substr($2,1,3)=="301" && $15=="996")
||
    ($15=="429" && $5>=030000 && $5<=035000)
```

Your tests for `$5` are only applied to lines where `$15=="429"` is true, which isn't the case in your example output lines.

Use parentheses to change that:

```
awk -F, '{if(substr($2,1,3)=="301" && ($15=="996" || $15=="429") && $5>=030000 && $5<=035000) print $2"|"$15"|"$5}' 2017020* | head -10
```

As a general rule, I would always parenthesize expressions with mixed logical AND and OR in any language even if not strictly necessary. This aids readability and avoids nasty surprises (there are languages out there with different precedence for AND and OR...).

Comment: Not only in awk, that's basically how **AND** and **OR** work.